# html <select> - does it work on cordova/phonegap app?

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, ripple

I'm developing a cordova 3.0 app and I'm testing it with ripple emulator.

I used a `<select>` html element like this:

```
  <select id="selector" >
   <option value="2"> 
        ...
   </option>
   <option value="4">   
        ...
   </option>
  </select>
```

and on ripple emulator I see it like we see `<select>` elements on websites, like this:
[image]

I'd like to know whether it works fine on Android, iOS etc... and how it will be shown on the real mobile device.

If using `<select>` on a mobile cordova app is not a good practice, what could I use to replace it? I'm also using jQuery 1.11.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I know native browsers will take over the dropdown view unless you apply any extra style like in JQM `data-native-menu="false"`.

In android, it'll look like

[image: ex1]

in lower android versions

[image: ex2]

in iOS

[image: ex3]

Now this changes with OS/browser versions,not sure. But if you want consistent look in all device, then you need something like that in JQM which can override existing dropdown style.